# SQL Server 2014 Connection String

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I've got some problems with my Connection string. Seached the web for some mistakes but didn't got any further. Is there something changed between SQL Server versions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="BeursTD.Properties.Settings.sdtcaptConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Initial Catalog=sdtcapt;User ID=XXXX;Password=XXXX"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you also post the error you are getting? And before trying to connect in your application, try with Management Studio (SSMS) first.

Comment: The error I get is just Can't Connect to DB.
It's a program written for us, but it worked fine on SQL 2008 R2. Unfortunately the version isn't supported by windows 10

Comment: The port number for a SQL Server named instance is dynamically configured.  The default instance would be on 1433.  Leave off the port number and you should be able to connect.  If you need to specify the port, you'll need to go into the configuration manager and look to see what port was assigned through the installation.

Comment: I am running SQL-Server Express 2008 R2 on Windows 10 without any problems.

Comment: Also you can visit http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ there a lot of samples connection strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without the ,1433!

```
"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=sdtcapt;User ID=XXXX;Password=XXX"
```

Comment: Thanks it's fixed, added that port for the 2008 version and now didn't think that would fix it.

thanks again!

Comment: Do you got any ideas for how to make it not Local? Because I need to make a connection with around 12 devices.

Comment: Enable TCPIP  connections on your Express instance, then use: MyServer\SQLEXPRESS as Data Source

Comment: Enabled TCP/IP and it's set on port 1433 don't know if that has any influence. Furthermore if I change it from Levi to MyServer it can't connect to the database anymore.

Comment: Of course replace Myserver with the dns name or ip address of the server hosting sql express - also make sure the sql browser service is running

Comment: Thanks! That solved it forgot to check the browser sevice!

Answer (score 0):

I would really write that as:

```
"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=sdtcapt;Trusted_Connection=yes"
```

BUT, are you sure SQL Server service is running on your machine and have an instance named SQLExpress, and has a database called "sdtCapt"?

Comment: Not really fixed :) Are you sure that you would like to use with UID, PWD in the config? I would prefer using windows authentication.